# C# SharpCompress Append to Existing Archive

Tags: c#

I am using SharpCompress (https://sharpcompress.codeplex.com) but I am struggling to append to ZIP files.

I have tried FileMode.Append on the Stream but it still overwrites the ZIP and only one file is in the ZIP file after process.

I cannot use the process to all of the files at once because not all files are available at any point in time

```
WriterOptions writerOptions = new WriterOptions(CompressionType.LZMA);
using (var zip = File.Open(strLogPath + "\\" + ArchiveName(strFile, strArchiveInterval), FileMode.Append))
//using (var zip = File.OpenWrite(strLogPath + "\\" + ArchiveName(strFile, strArchiveInterval)))
using (var zipWriter = WriterFactory.Open(zip, ArchiveType.Zip, writerOptions))
{
    zipWriter.Write(Path.GetFileName(strFile), strFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [SharpCompress test code](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/blob/master/test/SharpCompress.Test/Zip/ZipArchiveTests.cs) includes this example:

```
[Fact]
public void Zip_Random_Write_Add()
{
    string jpg = Path.Combine(ORIGINAL_FILES_PATH, "jpg\\test.jpg");
    string scratchPath = Path.Combine(SCRATCH_FILES_PATH, "Zip.deflate.mod.zip");
    string unmodified = Path.Combine(TEST_ARCHIVES_PATH, "Zip.deflate.mod.zip");
    string modified = Path.Combine(TEST_ARCHIVES_PATH, "Zip.deflate.mod2.zip");

    base.ResetScratch();
    using (var archive = ZipArchive.Open(unmodified))
    {
        archive.AddEntry("jpg\\test.jpg", jpg);
        archive.SaveTo(scratchPath, CompressionType.Deflate);
    }
    CompareArchivesByPath(modified, scratchPath);
}
```

So presumably in your case you need to do something like this:

```
string zipPath = Path.Combine(strLogPath, ArchiveName(strFile, strArchiveInterval));
string entryPath = @"where\you\want\it\in\the\zip";
string filePath = @"C:\temp\newfiletoadd";
using (var archive = ZipArchive.Open(zipPath)))
{
    archive.AddEntry(entryPath, filePath);
    archive.SaveTo(zipPath, CompressionType.LZMA);
}
```

If it complains that it can't overwrite the file because it's already open for reading (since I haven't tested this), you might need some extra steps to save a new archive to a temporary file (or memory stream if it's small), then delete the original, then move the temporary file to the original location.